# sqlite select method implement issue for iOS

Tags: ios, select, sqlite

I am trying to retrieve some data from my sqlite table base on a date, but I am getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=EXC_1386_GPFLT) error. Here is my method to fetch data-

```
 -(NSMutableArray*)fetchDataFromTable:(NSString*)tableName whenDate:(NSString*)activeDate{

NSMutableArray *resultArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from %@ where ActiveDate = \"%@\"", tableName, activeDate];

        if ([self canOpenDatabase]) { //checks if database can be openned
            sqlite3_stmt *statement=nil;

            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
                while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW){
                    NSMutableArray *fetchedResults=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                    int numberOfColumns = sqlite3_column_count(statement);

                    for (int i=0; i< numberOfColumns; i++){
                        char *dataAsChars = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, i);

                        if (dataAsChars != NULL) {
                            NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:dataAsChars];
                            [fetchedResults addObject:dataString];
                        }
                    }
                    [resultArray addObject:fetchedResults];

                    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
                    sqlite3_close(database);
                }
            }
            else{
                NSLog(@"Data can not be retrived");
            }
            return resultArray;
        }
        else{
             return resultArray;
        }
    }
```

I also trying printing the query. It shows

```
select * from Time_table where ActiveDate = "2016-01-01"
```

Please Help me out.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues.

1. Pair the call to `sqlite3_close` with the success of opening the database.
2. Pair the call to `sqlite_finalize` with the success of preparing the statement.
3. Don't close the database or finalize the statement inside the loop.
4. Don't build queries using `stringWithFormat`. Properly bind values into the prepared statement.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was very obvious yet very intuitive. I am glad that I faced this issue. At least I won't do it again. So, here is the simple fix and the reason behind it-

In case of database object fetching, EXC_BAD_ACCESS normally happens when -

- An object is not initialised or
- An object is already released untimely

So, in case, I were never to use the prepared statement or completely done working with the statement, I should use `sqlite_finalize`. In may method, I used the statement after I finalised the statement.

So the easy fix was to finalise after the while statement-

```
-(NSMutableArray*)fetchDataFromTable:(NSString*)tableName whenDate:(NSString*)activeDate{
     NSMutableArray *resultArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from %@ where ActiveDate = \"%@\"", tableName, activeDate];

    if ([self canOpenDatabase]) {
        sqlite3_stmt *statement=nil;

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW){
                NSMutableArray *fetchedResults=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                int numberOfColumns = sqlite3_column_count(statement);
                for (int i=0; i< numberOfColumns; i++){
                    char *dataAsChars = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, i);

                    if (dataAsChars != NULL) {
                        NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:dataAsChars];
                        [fetchedResults addObject:dataString];
                    }
                }
                [resultArray addObject: fetchedResults];
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"Data can not be retrived");
        }
        sqlite3_close(database);
        return resultArray;
    }
    else{
         return resultArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: You moved the call to `sqlite3_finalize` to the wrong location. It should be between where you had it before and where you have it now.

Comment: Thanks, I copied the wrong code. I had it right in my project. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Now the call to `sqlite3_close` is in the wrong place. It should be just before the 1st call to `return resultArray;`.

Comment: I don't think, that causes any issue. it is working fine in my case. Is there any particular reason for which I shouldn't close there?

Comment: The close should be paired with the open. As you have it now, if the database is opened but the statement fails to prepare, you don't close the database as you should.

Comment: Much better. Now you just need to replace the `stringWithFormat` for building your query with the proper use of variable binding into the prepared statement.

Comment: Thanks for all your help.